# Open accordion panel on validation error (Asp.net)

Tags: jquery, asp.net

When I click submit the form validates correctly.
It displays all the information entered in the first tab and if you manually click the second or third tabs, it displays validation error messages next to the input boxes in the 2nd and 3rd tabs..

What I would like it to do it activate the tab with the first instance of a validation error, so the user knows what they have missed. i.e. in the above example the second tab opens when they click submit.

I want to open which tab or tabs gives error when textboxs not validate.

I use jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js.
I have tried adding the following:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                    $("#accordion").accordion({ autoHeight: false });
                });

            
            </script>
            <div id="accordion">
                <h3>
                    <a href="#">Kişisel Bilgiler</a></h3>
                <div id="dvKisisel">
                    <div class="radsatir">
                        <div class="radw360">
                            <div class="radw120 radleft">
                                Adınız</div>
                            <div class="radw200 radright">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAd" Width="180" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAd" ErrorMessage="&nbsp;&nbsp;Adınızı Giriniz!" SetFocusOnError="True" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="odeme"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </div>
                          
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radsatir">
                        <div class="radw360">
                            <div class="radw120 radleft">
                                Soyadınız</div>
                            <div class="radw200 radright">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSoyad" Width="180" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtSoyad" ErrorMessage="&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;Soyadınızı Giriniz!" SetFocusOnError="True" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="odeme"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radsatir">
                        <div class="radw360">
                            <div class="radw120 radleft">
                                Email</div>
                            <div class="radw200 radright">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" Width="180" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" ErrorMessage="&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;Email Adresinizi Giriniz!" SetFocusOnError="True" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="odeme"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" ErrorMessage="&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;Geçerli Mail Giriniz!" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="odeme"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator> 
                                <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvEmail" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" 
                        ErrorMessage="Bu mail adresi zaten kayıtlı!" onservervalidate="cvEmail_ServerValidate" 
                        ValidationGroup="odeme" Display="Dynamic"></asp:CustomValidator>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radsatir">
                        <div class="radw360">
                            <div class="radw120 radleft">
                                Cep Telefonu</div>
                            <div class="radw200 radright">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCepTelefonu" Width="180" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCepTelefonu" ErrorMessage="&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;Cep Telefonunuzu Giriniz!" SetFocusOnError="True" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="odeme"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCepTelefonu" ErrorMessage="&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;Geçerli Cep Numarası Giriniz!&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;(Örn:555-555-55-55)" ValidationExpression="^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}$" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="odeme"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h3>
                    <a href="#">Fatura Bilgileri</a></h3>
                <div>
                    <div class="radsatir">
                        <div class="radw360">
                            <div class="radw120 radleft">
                                Fatura Adı</div>
                            <div class="radw200 radright">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtFaturaAdi" Width="180" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtFaturaAdi" ErrorMessage="&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;Fatura Adını Yazınız!" SetFocusOnError="True" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="odeme"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radsatir">
                        <div class="radw360">
                            <div class="radw120 radleft">
                                Fatura TC Kimlik No / Vergi No</div>
                            <div class="radw200 radright">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtFaturaVergiNo" Width="180" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtFaturaVergiNo" ErrorMessage="&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;TC Kimlik No/Vergi No Giriniz!" SetFocusOnError="True" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="odeme"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtFaturaVergiNo" ErrorMessage="&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;Hatalı Giriş!" ValidationExpression="([0-9])+" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="odeme"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
<div class="radsatir">
            <asp:Button CssClass="greenbutton" ID="btnSiparisTamamla" runat="server" Text="Siparişi Tamamla"
                OnClick="btnSiparisTamamla_Click" ValidationGroup="odeme" />
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Call common validation function on tab change, refer below coding template:

```
<div id="tab1">
   Tab 1
</div>
<div id="tab2">
   Tab 2
</div>
<div id="tab3">
   Tab 3
</div>

function validation(){
//validation code here return true if everything is good and false if some thing is wrong
}

$("#tab1").click(function(){
   if(validation()){
      return true;
   }else{
      return false;
   }
});
$("#tab2").click(function(){
   if(validation()){
      return true;
   }else{
      return false;
   }
});
$("#tab3").click(function(){
   if(validation()){
      return true;
   }else{
      return false;
   }
});
```

Comment: I add codes this https://codeshare.io/5wyxLx but ss this http://prntscr.com/fcab7w

normally form seens this:
http://prntscr.com/fcabq3

Comment: Why not use Accordion Control of asp.net instead. Try to use this example http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1e050f/accordion-control-in-ajax-control-toolkit-Asp-Net/.